# how to replace time duration using regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, splunk

I'm struggling with some regexp.  I'm writing a splunk query, one of the field is a time duration and I need to do some text replacement.  The following are sample values and their replacement.

```
value| replacement
01| 01 sec
01:02| 01 min 02 sec
01:02:03|01 hr 02 min 03 sec
01+02:03:04|01 day 02 hr 03 min 04 sec
```

any help will be appreciated.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
((((?<day>\d{2})\+)?(?<hr>\d{2}):)?(?<min>\d{2}):)?(?<sec>\d{2})
```

The above works fine in .NET and should be 100% compatible with perl (which, according to the docs, is the flavor splunk uses).

You'll have to add the "sec", "min", etc. stuff yourself, but you can use named capture to extract just the numbers (and you can test whether the named capture succeeded to determine how much to add).

Decomposition:

```
(
    (
        (
            (?<day>\d{2})\+   # day is optional, but req hr ('+' not captured)
        )?
        (?<hr>\d{2}):         # hr is optional, but req min (':' not captured)
    )?
    (?<min>\d{2}):            # min is optional, but req sec (':' not captured)
)?
(?<sec>\d{2})                 # sec is required
```

Comment: i tried your regexp on this online validator http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html.  It didn't return any match.  I used this target text 23:14:32.  I think the expression is missing the last ) at the very end, which I added in my test.  any idea?  thanks.

Comment: @SO - I believe the javascript flavor does not support named capture.

Comment: not tested your regex above, however, @SO, When I started off with Splunk, I was directed to http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ which is pretty good.